# How do I make a point bigger? (tkz-euclide)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

For example let's draw a segment:

[image: segment]

The *code* for the segment:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}
\tikz{
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/A, 5/0/B}
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B)
\tkzLabelPoints(A,B)
\tkzDrawSegment(A,B)
}
\end{document}
```

I would like to make the point  `A` bigger. How do I do that?

Comment: Tip: Put all your `\tkzDrawPoints`s after all your `\tkzDrawSegments`s. That way, your points appear on top of the lines instead of the other way around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to modify a **single point or a subset of points** you will need to plot the points of different style independently which allows you to set the local options `\tkzDrawPoints[<local options>](<name>)` for this single point (or a subset of points):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}
\tikz{
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/A, 5/0/B}
\tkzDrawPoints[size=20](A)
\tkzDrawPoints(B)
\tkzLabelPoints(A,B)
\tkzDrawSegment(A,B)
}
\end{document}
```

for both points use:

```
\tkzDrawPoints[size=20](A,B)
```

[image]

If you want to modify a **all subsequent following points** you can use `tkzSetUpPoint`

```
...
\tkzSetUpPoint[size = 20]
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B)
...
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set up your points using `\tkzSetUpPoint[<drawing specifications>]` as required.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}

\tkzSetUpPoint[shape = circle, color = black,%
size = 12,fill = red]

\tikz{
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/A, 5/0/B}
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B)
\tkzLabelPoints(A,B)
\tkzDrawSegment(A,B)
}
\end{document}
```

[image]